# How can I display all values of an array in C#

Tags: c#, string

I am new at C#, so sorry for the basic question :)

I have a text box, in this text box i write an input.

And then I want an output with only the uneven number position of the string.

So I wrote a for loop...

```
string strVariable = txt.Text;

            for (int c = 0; c > strVariable.Length; c++)
            {
                string[] Array = new string[strVariable.Length];                    
                Array [c] = strVariable.Substring(c, 1);   
            }
```

But how can I now enter all the values of the Array in one string?

So for example I have the word "Test" in the strVariable string
Then in the Array string I have "Ts"
but how can I output "Ts"

Comment: `c > strVariable.Length` seriously?

Comment: wat else should I write?

Comment: `<` would be a good start

Comment: okey :) thanks. And what do you think of my question.

Answer (score 3):

There are undoubtedly many ways to collapse an array of strings into a single string.  One such way would be to [use `string.Concat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wkb0y3w.aspx):

```
var result = string.Concat(myArray);
```

Note that I rename your variable to `myArray` here.  For starters, you'll want to follow language conventions with variable names which in this case specify that the first letter should be lowercase.  But more importantly, you definitely *don't* want to name a variable with the same name as [a class in a namespace that you're using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx).  That would cause untold confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a simple for loop without using an array like in the code below :

```
        string result;
        for (int c = 0; c < txt.text.Length; c++)
        {
            result += txt.text.Substring(c, 1);   
        }
```